# Grails Beans - defining list of Values

Tags: grails, groovy, javabeans, spring-ws

I need to add more than one XSD to my list of XSDs in this Grails Spring Bean :

```
springws {
    wsdl {
        Holiday {
           wsdlName= 'Holiday-v2'
            xsds= '/WEB-INF/Holiday.xsd'
            portTypeName = 'HolidayPort'
            serviceName = 'HolidayService'
            locationUri = grails.serverURL + '/services/hr/v2/Holiday'
            targetNamespace = 'http://www.myveryimportantcompany.com/hr/v2/definitions'
        }
    }
```

}

So I want to pass in more than one value to xsds ... how do I represent this in Groovy / Grails?

Thanks

Comment: Was the answer helpful?

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are referring to springws plugin. You can use multiple schemas as below:

```
springws {
        wsdl {
            Holiday {
               wsdlName= 'Holiday-v2'
                xsds= '''/WEB-INF/Holiday.xsd,
                         /WEB-INF/Example1.xsd,
                         /WEB-INF/Example2.xsd'''
                portTypeName = 'HolidayPort'
                serviceName = 'HolidayService'
                locationUri = grails.serverURL + '/services/hr/v2/Holiday'
                targetNamespace = 'http://www.myveryimportantcompany.com/hr/v2/definitions'
            }
        }

}
```

You can refer [this sample project](https://github.com/dmahapatro/grails-springws-sample) for more details about the usage of springws plugin.